# Вывод данных из БД при загрузке JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Мне нужно, чтобы в начальной login.jsp,

```
 <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
```

выводился список товаров, который берется из базы данных, и который в свою очередь получается после обработки контроллера по адресу

```
/controller?command=MainPageCommand
```

Другими словами, перед тем, как загрузилась первая страница я должен загрузить на неё список товаров.
Возможно, нужно в welcome-file записать адресс, я пробовал, но чего-то не выходит, подскажите каким образом без js можно осуществить это всё.